# Writing a matrix as multiplication of orthogonal and diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given is the matrix A = \begin{pmatrix}
  5 & 3  \\
  0 & -4 \\
  \end{pmatrix}

I would like to write this matrix as the product A = $U S V^T$

whereas U and V both are orthogonal matrices and S is a diagonal matrix. What is the approach to find suitable matrices?

Comment: Do you know how to diagonalize a matrix? Do you know about SVD decomposition?

Comment: I did not yet, but will read about it. Then with these two techniques it should be possible?

Comment: Yes, it's a direct consequence of the SVD decomposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
  5 & 3  \\
  0 & -4 \\
  \end{pmatrix}$$

We want to find the Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) where $U$ and $V$ both are orthogonal matrices and $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix, such that:

$$A = U \cdot \Sigma \cdot V^T$$

We arrive at:

$$A = U \cdot \Sigma \cdot V^T = \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 3  \\  0 & -4 \\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}  \\  -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & -\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \\ \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 2\sqrt{10} & 0 \\  0 & \sqrt{10} \\ \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: Thank you, in the meantime I arrived at this result too, but now I am sure it is correct!

Comment: @GuestGuest: you are very welcome!

Comment: You killed the problem, Amzoti! $\checkmark +1$

Comment: @amWhy: Hadn't done one of those in ages, so it was fun! :-0